# How to load different zshrc file via commandline option?

Tags: bash, zsh

I used to do this with bash...

```
/bin/bash --rcfile /home/sindhu/bin/misc_scripts/shellrc/.bashrc_1
```

how can I accomplish the same with zsh?

Thank you.

Comment: is this helps you : 'http://ivan.fomentgroup.org/blog/2010/01/29/zsh-organize-your-zshrc-should-work-for-bash-as-well/'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can approximate that feature by using the `ZDOTDIR` variable.

In a directory perhaps like this:

```
mkdir /home/sindhu/bin/misc_scripts/shellrc/.zshrc_1
```

create a file called `.zshrc` containing your alternative startup script. Then you can start zsh like this:

```
ZDOTDIR=/home/sindhu/bin/misc_scripts/shellrc/.zshrc_1 zsh
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a small wrapper script:

```
source $1
zsh -f -d
```

The first line sources your alternative RC file. The second starts a new Z shell without sourcing any other RC files. See zshoptions(1) for the options -d and -f (GLOBAL_RCS, RCS).

Comment: I can imagine this won't work for many use cases, one example being $1 contains a set of useful zsh functions. They won't be available in the child zsh process