# Running a zsh alias with WSL in a ConEmu startup task

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, conemu

My current WSL2 + ConEmu + bash/zsh setup works as expected.

I have some aliases set up in my `.zshrc`:

```
//.zshrc
alias mycommand1="[does some stuff]"
alias mycommand2="[does other stuff]"
```

What I want to achieve is to have a **ConEmu startup Task** that would run `mycommand1` and `mycommand2` in two separate tabs, and then leave these tabs open.

This requires ConEmu to load up WSL+bash+zsh, and then run the command.

As per [the docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/BashOnWindows.html), my default Task currently runs native wsl.exe:

```
// {Bash::bash} Task commands
%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt --distribution Ubuntu-20.04
```

And, *after carefully reading all the docs* ([1](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsTasks.html), [2](https://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html), [3](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html)) and spending a fair amount of time on fiddling with params, I was only able to produce following attempts:

```
%windir%\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 -new_console:pm:/mnt -- ls
// logs my Windows User directory and prompts "Press Enter or Esc to exit..."
```

```
%windir%\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 -new_console:pm:/mnt -- mycommand1
// logs "zsh:1: command not found: mycommand1" and prompts "Press Enter or Esc to exit..."
```

I would appreciate some pointers:

- How can I pass a command from wsl.exe that will be run from within the Ubuntu context, with all my bash/zsh configs?
- How can I do that from ConEmu Task, ensuring that after running the command the tabs stay open with a regular zsh shell prompt?
- Is there anything else I need to know to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66954673/13020139) for passing commands to Ubuntu from `wsl.exe`? The only thing I'm not sure about is if you need to run `source ~/.bashrc` first (and whatever other configs you need to load up).

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because someone thought this wasn't necessarily a "programming question", but I disagree (although barely).  At its core, it goes to shell scripting, a topic that is allowed on Stack Overflow.  Admittedly, the fact that it is wrapped up in a ConEmu question does obscure that a bit, though.

Comment: Although if the downvote is because it contains "multiple questions", then fair enough ;-)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I agree it is a "question wrapped in another question" case, but I really wanted to avoid falling into an X/Y problem trap. I don't feel competent enough in this field (yet) to split this case into separate concise questions.

Comment: No worries, I agree, and I upvoted since you've clearly done your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this as a second answer in case it works for you (and it very well may).

My (very long) other answer assumes that you need the alias to run in the same subshell instance that continues to run.  If you are okay with the alias running, then `exec`'ing a *new* shell, then this answer will be **much** simpler.

Just create a `conemu_start.txt` (or whatever you want to call it, wherever you want to place it), with the following:

```
>%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:t:"MyCommand1" -cur_console:pm:/mnt ~ --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec zsh -li -c "mycommand1; zsh -li"
>%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:t:"MyCommand2" -cur_console:pm:/mnt ~ --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec zsh -li -c "mycommand2; zsh -li"
```

As with the other answer, in ComEmu, set *Settings* -> *Startup* -> *Tasks file* to this file.

That's it.  The `-li` will cause the shells to be *login* (which processes `.zprofile`) and *interactive* (which processes `.zshrc`).  That way, the aliases get defined, executed, and then another subshell is run to keep the ConEmu tab open.

Comment: This does precisely what I needed. Thank you! I really appreciate also your other detailed answer, I learned a lot from it!

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer:

- Create a new startup directory with a new `.zshrc` that (a) sources the existing profile, and (b) runs aliases based on an environment variable set before starting the shell.
- Start each shell (tab) by setting `ZDOTDIR`, `RUN_ALIAS`, and `exec`ing `zsh -li`
- Run these through the `wsl.exe` command
- Set a ConEmu startup file to run the appropriate commands

#### Step 1:  Launch `zsh`, run an alias, and keep the session from exiting

Assumptions: I'm going to assume you really do want these to be aliases.  If you want to run other arbitrary scripts/commands, you can still do it, but it will require a slight change to the instructions.  I've summarized the changes needed in-line below.

There are several techniques you could use to keep the shell running, but the ones suggested [in this question](https://superuser.com/q/91881/1210833) require you to either:

- Create a nested shell, which is not ideal.
- Or [modify](https://superuser.com/a/790681/1210833) your existing `~/.zshrc` to "special case" a launch with your command.  It's a neat trick, but I'm not a fan of changes to the default startup files when they can be avoided.  That said, it's much easier.  If you want to go this route, I'll add some info at the bottom of this answer on how to do it.

But the `~/.zshrc` solution got me thinking.  If you want to run any arbitrary command at startup, and yet keep the shell running, the answer *is* `.zshrc`.
You just need to have a *different* `.zshrc` that you use for the "special case".

`bash` has the `--rcfile` option to select the file to run at startup, but the `zsh` equivalent is a bit trickier, as it involves setting `$ZDOTDIR` and changing the location from which `zsh` reads its startup (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728257/11810933)).

So to start, let's create a config directory for your "run an alias" config:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/zsh/startup/run_alias/`
```

Or wherever you want, of course.  Then, in that directory, create the following:

`~/.local/share/zsh/startup/run_alias/.zshrc`:

```
if [ -f $HOME/.zshrc ]; then
  . $HOME/.zshrc
fi

if [ -v RUN_ALIAS ] && alias | grep -q "^$RUN_ALIAS="; then
  eval "$RUN_ALIAS"
fi

unset RUN_ALIAS
unset ZDOTDIR
```

And `~/.local/share/zsh/startup/run_alias/.zprofile`:

```
if [ -f $HOME/.zprofile ]; then
  . $HOME/.zprofile
fi
```

The conditionals, of course, are optional if you always know that your `$HOME/.zsh` and `.zprofile` exist.  But better to be safe.

Repeat for `mycommand2`.

If it's not obvious, this will:

- Call your existing `$HOME/.zshrc` to define the aliases (and anything else in your startup)
- Check to make sure the contents of `$RUN_ALIAS` really is an alias (some added security)
- Call the alias defined in the `RUN_ALIAS` variable
- Unset the RUN_ALIAS variable (cleanup)
- Unset the special `ZDOTDIR` so that future subshell invocations will use the files in `$HOME`.
- Have the new `.zprofile` source the original as well

You can now test this by calling a subshell with:

```
ZDOTDIR=~/.local/share/zsh/startup/run_alias RUN_ALIAS=mycommand1 zsh -li
```

But of course, that leaves an extra subshell running (`$SHLVL` is 2).  So, use `exec` instead:

```
ZDOTDIR=~/.local/share/zsh/startup/run_alias RUN_ALIAS=mycommand1 exec zsh -li
```

$SHLVL is now 1, your command/alias should have been executed *in the current (and only) shell*, and it is still running.

To get that running in WSL, we do need to start an "outer shell" (that is replaced by `exec`ing the proper `zsh`).  I tend to use `sh` for this, like so:

```
wsl ~ --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec sh -c "ZDOTDIR=`$HOME/.local/share/zsh/startup/run_alias RUN_ALIAS=mycommand1 exec zsh -li" # PowerShell quoted
wsl ~ --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec sh -c "ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.local/share/zsh/startup/run_alias RUN_ALIAS=mycommand1 exec zsh -li" # CMD (and ConEmu) quoted
```

Side note:  My Windows Terminal profiles for `wsl` actually used to look very similar to this.  I've streamlined them a bit, but I still set an environment variable (the title I want for the tab) before starting my shell (`fish`) and `tmux`.

Side note #2:  My original answer used two separate `ZDOTDIR`'s and corresponding directories.  This would still be useful if you wanted to execute different *commands* (as opposed to *aliases*).  In that case, create additional directories, and point to them by changing the `ZDOTDIR`.  Just put your commands in the modified `.zshrc` in the corresponding directory.

#### Run the commands at ConEmu Startup

The easy part.  Create a `conemu_start.txt` anywhere (and any name), really:

```
>%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:t:"MyCommand1" -cur_console:pm:/mnt ~ --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec sh -c "ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.local/share/zsh/startup/run_alias RUN_ALIAS=mycommand1 exec zsh -li"
>%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:t:"MyCommand2" -cur_console:pm:/mnt ~ --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec sh -c "ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.local/share/zsh/startup/run_alias RUN_ALIAS=mycommand2 exec zsh -li"
```

In ComEmu, set *Settings* -> *Startup* -> *Tasks file* to this file.

That should do it.  Starting ConEmu should now open two tabs with `zsh`, one for each of these aliases/commands.

#### Alternative:  Modify existing `.zshrc` to run an alias based on an environment variable

Add the following to the bottom of `~/.zshrc`:

```
if [ -v RUN_ALIAS ] && alias | grep -q "^$RUN_ALIAS="; then
  eval "$RUN_ALIAS"
fi
```

Test it with:

```
RUN_ALIAS=mycommand1 exec zsh -li
```

And then change the `conemu_start.txt` to:

```
>%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:t:"MyCommand1" -cur_console:pm:/mnt ~ --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec sh -c "RUN_ALIAS=mycommand1 exec zsh -li"
>%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:t:"MyCommand2" -cur_console:pm:/mnt ~ --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec sh -c "RUN_ALIAS=mycommand2 exec zsh -li"
```