# A way for my Windows 10 to tell my Linux subsystem to do run something via a batch file or similar?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Windows 10 system with a Ubuntu 18.04 linux subsystem installed.  I have a batch file in my windows 10 startup folder that connects to my office vpn and then maps a few drives with credentials.

What I would like, if it was possible, was at the end of my windows 10 start up batch file that I wrote, there was a way to then tell my Ubuntu 18.04 to run a `.sh` file I have writtenthat then mounts the mapped drives I just mapped on my Windows host.  I already have the `.sh` file written, current I just wait for my windows batch file to finish, then go into my subsystem and manually run the `.sh` file.  I figure I could always set up flask servers on both to communicate, but I wanted to know if there's a better more direct way for the two OS's to communicate.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?  After the completion of a `.bat` file on Windows 10, Windows sends a message to it's linux subsystem to run a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `wsl` command to send linux commands to your wsl distribution. For instance:

`wsl bash /path/mybashfile.sh`

Tested on command prompt and powershell.

See `wsl -help` for more info on `wsl` options.

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: Apologies.  I meant to type a full thing, accidentally submitted, couldn't edit for 5 minutes and then forgot.

What I ended up doing in my .sh file was 


#!/bin/bash

sudo mount -t drvfs R: /mnt/r

sudo mount -t drvfs P: /mnt/p


I put this at the end of my batch file so the rest of the windows mappings/file stuff happened first.  It does prompt me for my linux password when it gets to this point, but I am ok with that.  It works now.